# Should one say "习题解答与提示" or "习题解答或提示"？

Tags: word-choice, conjunction

If the appendix of a textbook consists of the solutions to some exercises and hints to other exercises, should it be named as "习题解答与提示"or"习题解答或提示"？

Edit:

The following is from 《群表示论》by Prof. 丘维声, who is a Chinese native speaker:

[image]

Comment: 习题解析 is more concise.

Comment: 解析 means "explanation" a hint is not an explanation

Comment: If you look up in the dictionary, 与 means "and", 或 means "or". So answer can be deducted simply from a dictionary. This question doesn't show any efforts.

Answer (score 2):

正确的说法是习题解答与提示，也可以用习题解答和提示。和 means and, 或means or.

Answer (score 1):

习题解答与提示 means it contains both answers and hints to all the questions. If you don't want to look at the answer right away, you can look at the hints first to see if you can figure it out with a little help.

习题解答或提示 means it contains either answer or hints, meaning it can be answers to some questions and hints for other questions. I think it make very little sense to not list all the answers to all the questions. So, 习题解答与提示 should be the correct name

Answer (score 0):

I think 习题解答与提示 is the right translation. At least that's what I remember seeing in my textbooks. I don't remember seeing any other use cases in any textbooks I have used.

Logically, I think it means this is the section that includes 习题解答与提示. It doesn't matter whether some questions have solution or tips only. 习题解答或提示 is for an individual question, but this is a section title.

I feel 和 is more used when you speak, not on paper, in context like this.